# What is the total speedup?

Tags: performance, cpu-architecture

This is not homework. I'm taking a computer architecture MOOC on my own time. There is a problem I can't figure out and maybe someone can help me.
Here it is:

Memory operations currently take 30% of the execution time.

- A new widget called a "cache" speeds up 80% of memory operations by a factor of 4.
- A second new widger called a "L2 cache" speeds up 1/2 the remaining 20% by a factor of 2.

What is the total speedup?

Here is the formula that is used to calculate the speedup:

> Speedup = 1 / [(1 - Non-speedup portion) + (Sped up portion
>   1)/speedup1 + (Sped up portion 2)/speedup2 + ...]

I calculated it as follows:

```
Speedup = 1 / [0.7 + 0.3*0.8/4 + 0.3*0.2*0.5/2 + 0.3*0.2*0.5] = 1.2422
```

But the answer is wrong which indicates that my reasoning is wrong, but I can't figure out where it is wrong. Can someone help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: My guess would be that the new runtime relative to unoptimized is computed by: ``0.8 * 0.25 + 0.2 * 0.5 = 0.3`` So your code runs at 30% of the original time.

Comment: @BitTickler Can you elaborate more on this, I'm not quite clear what you are trying to say.

Comment: For the Unoptimized code my model formula would be 1.0 (100% of the code)  * 1.0 (100% speed). Splitting that up to 80/20 would look like:  ``0.8 * 1.0 + 0.2 * 1.0 = 1.0``. Now you only need 1/4 of the time for the 0.8 part and 1/2 the time for the 0.2 part and you get my above formula.

Comment: @BitTickler I've tried that approach. It is telling me it a wrong answer.

Comment: There goes my theory! :( Wait - it runs in 30% of the time which is a speedup of 70% right?

Comment: This is a simple math exercise. It's really not a programming question at all. It's much more suitable for [math.se]. (The equation is the same whether you're dealing with memory operations or a stage in the manufacturing of widgets.)

Comment: One possibility would be that they figure hits on the L2 cache also take time to probe the L1 cache, and reads from memory include time to probe the L1 and l2 caches. That's not how things usually work in real life, but it could be the basis on which they're doing the math.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Then the phrasing of the question would be bad. They explicitely say that the L2 cache only affects the remaining 20% of the code. Omg textbook questions... half of the remaining 20%... ``0.8 * 0.25 + 0.1 * 1.0 + 0.1 * 0.5 = 0.35"

Comment: @JerryCoffin I agree with you, the wording is bad. Unfortunately I can't ask them to change it.

Comment: @KenWhite I thought it was a simple math exercise as well. But as it turns out it is not. I posted it here because I thought I might be missing something conceptually.

Comment: Try my latest guess - I think my general approach is right and I only overread the "half of the reamining 20%" part.

Comment: It *is* a simple math exercise, and if you'd posted it to [math.se] in the first place, you'd have gotten both an answer and a clear explanation of how it was reached by now, rather than *Try my latest guess* (no offense to @BitTickler intended).

Comment: @BitTickler That's exactly what I tried to do on my first attempt. It is telling me the answer is still wrong. I feel like I'm missing something, I just don't know what it is.

Comment: So ``2.857142857 = 1.0 / 0.35`` is wrong?? Tell them to learn MY math! lol

Comment: @KenWhite: As far as simple math goes, what he has in the question seems to be fine. The question here is really about what the original question was supposed to mean--and that's likely to be based on computer architecture.

Comment: @BitTickler They should learn MY math as well. :D There is one thing you are not accounting for. The other 70% of instructions are not sped up. 0.35 should be (at least in my mind) multiplied by 0.3 to account for 30% of memory instructions.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Any ideas what it could mean?

Comment: @flashburn: I've already given my best guess above.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Can you clarify your best guess? I don't quite see it. Sorry I'm a bit slow today.

Comment: Omg difficulty by obscurity. Now I overread that whole 30% thing.... ``1.0 / (0.7 * 1.0 + 0.3 * 0.8 * 0.25 + 0.3 * 0.1 * 1.0 + 0.3 * 0.1 * 0.5) = 1.242236025`` just as you stated in your question. So maybe your OldSpeed/NewSpeed ratio is not what they look for and instead something like relative %: (oldspeed-newspeed)/ oldspeed?

Comment: @BitTickler: That could be--i.e., instead of ratio of new speed to old speed, perhaps they just want the percentage reduction in time (e.g., "17 % faster", or equivalent expressed as a fraction/decimal)?

Comment: Would the answer be 1.2307692?

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Tried it. They are saying it is wrong.

Comment: http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi11/cse141/Slides/07_performance.pdf  If you look on p44 it deals with your problem.  But math is wrong on p45.

Comment: @BitTickler Unfortunately no. They are looking for total speedup, i.e. a ratio.

Comment: Try (with my sum formula above: (newSpeed - oldSpeed) / old speed = (0.805 - 1.0) / 1.0 = -0.195 = -19.5%

Comment: I come up with 1.2658,

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat It said it was a wrong answer.

Comment: @KenWhite It said it was a wrong answer. Just out of curiosity, what logic did you use?

Comment: If it is a microsoft MOC, maybe you have to convert all that to square inches  * square of yards or something! *chuckles*

Comment: If my answer was wrong, does it matter? If it had been right, I would write up an answer explaining how I got there, but there's no point in explaining how I got it wrong.

Comment: @BitTickler Lol. Unfortunately it is not a Microsoft MOOC.

Comment: @BitTickler I also tried -19.5 value. It didn't work.

Comment: If you read the link I posted, it says your groupings must be unique.  L2 and L1 cache are not unique.  Data must go into L2 before L1.  That is the trick.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedup defines speed up as ``Told/Tnew``. If we all agree that the Tnew is 0.805 and Told = 1.0 then I give up and suggest: screw it :)

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat They say "widgets" so it is nothing real/hardware/related.

Comment: @BitTickler Same question.  The widget is the cache.

Comment: Based on the answer you've posted, I've voted to close this as off-topic because it cannot be reproduced or was a typo. (In this case, it was simply a mistake caused by too many decimal places.)

Comment: @KenWhite It is very strange though. The MOOC accepted other answers with no problems. For some reason it treated this one with prejudice. But I agree with you, this topic should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

So as it turns out my fist answer was correct. As it happens the answer has to be with 2 digits after the decimal point. I.e it will consider 1.2422 as a wrong answer but 1.24 as a correct one. Sorry for the confusion everyone and thanks for the help.